# Download XLSX File from Salesforce with Data Validation

Tags: salesforce, xlsx, apex, lwc

Can anyone confirm if there is the possibility of downloading xlsx file with Data Validation Logic from Salesforce? I know we can download the xls file as XML Spreadsheet but I would like to know if we can do it using the XLSX file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is already discussed [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/130300/generate-xlsx-file-from-apex).

Note: if you are doing this in VF or are able to execute Javascript, you can easily use something like [sheetsJS](https://github.com/sheetjs/sheetjs) to convert a json representation of your data to XLSX.